# Visual Studio 2008 Pro - For Smart Device Development, is .NET COMPACT Framework automatically used?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am new to any sort of windows / .NET development but am preparing to develop an application for an embedded device that runs Windows CE using the .NET Compact Framework. I am downloaded the 90 day free trial of Visual Studio 2008 Pro which includes Smart Device development.

What throws me off is, that when I make a new Smart Device project, the dropdown where you select the framework you want to use is still the .NET versions that I have rather than any .NET Compact versions. However I believe .NETCF did come with my Visual Studio download, because when I downloaded the standalone .NETCF it gave the "do you want to modify or remove this already installed software" message. Furthermore you would think that for smart device applications, Visual Studio would automatically use .NETCF rather than .NET? But I don't know how to tell whether the project I made uses .NET or .NETCF.

My concern is that I'll develop an app that works fine with no errors and runs on the emulator(s) provided, only to find out that I've been using the entire .NET framework and have included dependencies that are not included in the .NET compact subset of it, and so it will not work on the actual device. Could someone tell me how to confirm that I am using .NETCF, or confirm that I am if all smart device projects are automatically using only .NETCF? And if I am actually using .NET, how do I switch so that it's .NET compact framework, noting that the dropdown when you select "new project" does not include any .NETCF versions?

Comment: At https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43357/Windows-Mobile-App-Development-Part-Creating-you you find a detailed description of starting first Smart Device project. The  available Target Platforms depend on the SDKs you installed. If you follow the article and the wizard, you will NOT use the full .NET framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the first New Project wizard shows the installed full .NET Framework versions, these will not be used for SmartDevice project:

[image]

Just after confirming the C# Smart Device Project Name and Solution directory you will get the option to select the Target Platform and ".Net Compact Framework version:"

[image]

.NET Full Framework applications will NOT run in emulator nor on any compact framework device. The assembly signatures will not match the system.
You can however run 'standard' Compact Framework applications on a system with Full .NET Framework. CF is a subset of FF.

If you selected CF2.0 you can later 'Upgrade Project' to make it use CF3.5.

The Target Platform can also be changed later on from Project Properties using "Change Target Platform".